# GitHub will not recognize any changed files or new files

Tags: github

UPDATE: Solution was github was somehow deleted from my remotes so I simply added it back. Thank you for all the help.

I have been working on my sample_app application from the Ruby on Rails tutorial and I had trouble with my db. I had to import my app from heroku now it is called shielded-dawn-xxxx. I've made changes and added new files. Git doesn't recognize any new files or changes and when I try to

git push

it says "everything is the same" when it clearly is very different. I tried

touch files

but there's a lot of files and it doesn't work anyways when I try to commit. I tried renaming the name back to sample_app but it still won't let me push to github.

Comment: did you commit the changes?

Comment: Nothing to commit (on branch master)

Comment: What is the output when you type in "git status"?

Comment: on branch master, nothing to commit, 2 commit ahead of heroku, git push pushes the app to heroku but not github

Comment: Github is not in your remotes, according to a comment on my answer.

Comment: got it, just added the remote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read at least the first two chapters of http://git-scm.com/book (more is recommended).

When you git push and "everything is the same" it means that from your last commit locally matches the last commit pushed to the server. I think you might be forgetting to commit, try `git status` and tell us what it says? Just to know more, also share with us what `git remote -v` shows. Renaming the app, won't affect git, since everything is stored in a .git folder inside.

Comment: git remote -v: heroku xxxxxxxxxx fetch, heroku xxxxxxxxxx push

Comment: A couple of commands `git ls-remote` and `git log --pretty=oneline -3` so we can see the commits both locally and on the remote.

Comment: From git@heroku.com:shielded-dawn-8895.git
2770994386c5ad8a02074bd5379145937e02e8a5        HEAD
2770994386c5ad8a02074bd5379145937e02e8a5        refs/heads/master

2770994386c5ad8a02074bd5379145937e02e8a5 microposts
a47b689f5046b23f17b12773f904dc34d1a68a17 microposts
356a9cae1769ffbf09158d9086eaede7ad60153e micropost

Comment: That's `git ls-remote` what about the other?

Comment: It's solved I had to add github to my remotes again because it was deleted for some reason.

Comment: So git push was pushing to the only remote where everything was up to date. I'm glad we could help... somehow